# Graph decomposition

Tags: graph-theory

I want to decompose a (undirected) graph, into non-overlapping, complete subgraphs (i.e. every vertex belongs to exactly one subgraph), such that the number of subgraphs is minimal.

Does anyone know if this problem has a name and if there's is a software solving it?

Comment: I don't know if this has a name, or if there is software to do it, but I doubt there would be.  Determining the size of the largest complete subgraph is hard in general... so finding the "minimal number" of subgraphs is probably also hard.  You might be able to get a "good" approximation easily though.

Comment: Graph decomposition usually looks for edge-disjoint components and if the components are cliques this is called "clique decomposition". Google gives you pointers. Are you sure you want vertex-disjoint components?

Comment: As described, it seems like your problem could always be solved by a single subgraph that contains all the vertices of the graph - in other words, the graph itself. Is there some other constraint on these subgraphs?

Comment: @gilleain the subgraphs must be complete.

Comment: @Leen Droogendijk yes i need vertex-disjoint components.

Comment: For your problem it is usual to talk about partitioning instead of decomposing. That is also a well-known problem called the "clique cover problem", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem